# How can I access the ftp server with username which contains slash character?

Tags: ftp-client

How can I access the ftp server with username which contains slash character?

I know how to use terminal to access to ftp server from terminal (Mac) as follow:

```
ftp username:password@server
```

but my username is quite special. It contains the slash character "/" such as:

ABC/XYZ

I tried to use quotes in this case, but it does not work:

```
ftp "ABC/XYZ":password@server
```

Could you help?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to escape the / with \ like

```
ftp ABC\/XZY:password@server
```

Comment: it doesn't work. It said "ftp can't lookup `ABC/XYZ': nodename nor seervname provided, or not known

Comment: I had a missspelling:
ftp ABC\/XYZ:password@server
Dont know if that matters
In general you shouldnt use any spezial characters in the username anyways if possible